# How do I change my default helmet?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I know that you can change your helmet in your inventory but I don't want to wear it all the time.

But when I change helmet it is on all the time so how do I change default helmet without wearing it all the time?

Answer (score 2):

You can find new helmets at any clothing store under the "Hats" section, and from the mask store at Vespucci Beach. Buying a new helmet from one of these places will automatically define it as your new default helmet.

However, you can still change it manually from your inventory anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your inventory and put on the helmet you want to be default.  Back out of the menu.  Then go back to the inventory and remove the helmet.  It is now your default helmet.